# "quickly design" and ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: quickly, 13.10, glade

I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 and then I installed quickly to develop some apps.

When I run "quickly run" or "quickly edit" everything is fine, but when run "quickly design" glade open and close directly. I tried uninstall and install quickly, but nothing and when try to open .ui file in my app directory, I can't to edit it because there is error in requirement. The version of glade I have 3.14.2

when create new file glade in glade it works fine.

Is there any way to let quickly use GTK2 instead GTK3? or fix force close?

Answer (score 6):

Here are precisions added to [bert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357184/quickly-design-and-ubuntu-13-10/376066#376066), about [the fix that worked for me](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glade/+bug/1242865/comments/25) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jfi/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It should then work.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a known issue with Glade on Ubuntu 13.10. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glade/+bug/1242865

The temporary fix as provided in comment #25 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glade/+bug/1242865/comments/25) works fine for me.